# Use custom Animation (MyAnimation extends Animation) to transition between two Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am trying to do a transition between two fragments using a 'flip animation.' I made my flip animation by writing a separate class called Flip3dAnimation that extends Animation. I use this elsewhere in my app and it works as intended. I would now like to use it to transition between to fragments. I am aware that the following method exists:

`setCustomAnimations(arg0, arg1)` on a FragmentTransaction object, however the two arguments to this method has to be xml resources. Since I wrote my own animation I do not have any animation declared in xml and I do not know of a way to get my own Flip3dAnimation type to appear as a valid xml tag in a res/anim/my_animation.xml file. Is this possible?

If above solution is not possible, then how would this be done?

EDIT: I am aware of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) tutorial, however as far as I understand, the `<objectAnimator>` tag is a property animation, which uses API level 11 and is not included in the support library. My app has to run on devices with Android older than 3.0, so this is not really an option, unless there is some way around it, that I do not know of?

Thank you.